# calling javascript in html in php- quotation already occupied

Tags: javascript, php, html, string

In PHP code I need to use echo to type some HTML code. Inside the HTML I called an event which start an JS code which needs to take a string.

```
<?php
echo "<input type='text' name='myname' onclick='startJScode(this, "Input your name")' />";
?>
```

To tell what to echo I used characters ", so I used ' to define strings in HTML. But theres none other quotation marks types left to define a string for Javascript code- using any of them will mix with ones already used.

How to deal with it then?

Comment: Escape your quotes : \

Comment: \ is used to tell the intepreter that it needs to be printed. It is not a special character.

Comment: You can also see the Heredoc notation just for fun.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use :

```
<?php
echo "<input type='text' name='myname' onclick='startJScode(this, \"Input your name\")' />";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
<?php
echo "<input type='text' name='myname' onclick=\"startJScode(this, 'Input your name')\" />";
?>
```

In

```
echo " ";
```

don't repeat double qoute like

wrong code

```
                             v //double quote ended here
echo "this is a "test" string";
     ^ //double quote started here
```

So you have need to use backslash before double quote if there is needed in between quote

right code

```
                v //use backslash
echo "this is a \"test\" string";
                      ^ //use backslash
```

Same issue for single quote

wrong code

```
                             v //double quote ended here
echo 'this is a 'test' string';
     ^ //double quote started here
```

right code

```
                v //use backslash
echo 'this is a \'test\' string';
                      ^ //use backslash
```

Otherwise

If starting and ending quote is double quote in between code will be single quote

```
echo "this is a 'test' string";
```

and

If starting and ending quote is single quote in between code will be double quote

```
echo 'this is a "test" string';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either escape the quotations marks using \

For example:

```
echo "<input type='text' name='myname' onclick='startJScode(this, \"Input your name\")' />"
```

This will escape the inside quotation marks.

Or you can use the [Heredoc syntax](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc)

Example:

```
$foo = <<<CODE
    <input type="text" name="myname" onclick="startJScode(this, 'Input your name')" />
CODE;
echo $foo;
```

Heredoc syntax is very convenient if you want to output XML\HTML with many different quotation marks since it allows you to omit the quotation mark for string.